# If a Buddhists was trapped with a predator animal in a cage, would they kill it?

Tags: ethics, karma

Since Buddhists believe that we shouldn't hurt animals, then would they kill one for survival?

Comment: FYI [one of Stack Exchange's general policies](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) says, "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site"

Comment: The question seems too general and there could be a spectrum of answers based off some of the vague terms you used in the question itself such as "Buddhist" . And there a lot of assumptions to be made in answering. I'd suggest, explore a little bit about Buddhist ethics (sīla); you will be able to come up with a better question.

Comment: Question closed due to being purely hypothetical and not serving a real purpose. Please read the policy on [*"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"*](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Lanka, why is this question closed? If you just think a little more, he is trying to know the karma of handling a life or death situation through a papa karma. Treeschapter should be given a chance to get a proper answer. Infact, this is questioned by lot of young followers. Most likely, in this case which is where Treeschapter is searching for an answer as he is still learning. He deserves a chance for an explanation.